# Blackberry browser field implementation

Tags: java, blackberry

I need to display any web page as a browser field,not browser session.I am building the app in 4.7 OS.Can anyone help me with sample code?

Answer (score 1):

On 4.7 you are stuck with the [old browser field](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field/package-summary.html). Also known as Browser Field 1. It renders HTML pretty close to how it was on 4.5 devices. There is no way to take advantage of the newer browser that you invoke via browser session. So, you can [forget about CSS2 or or JavaScript](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/net-rim-device-api-browser-field2/m-p/416465;jsessionid=9FD6C49D47A810131378B559EBEAD869) on the pages you want to render as a browser field. But for the fairly basic stuff it is good enough.

For the sample code - you really should check out and understand all the examples there are in the development package before starting writing the code. It will really save more time than take for learning. Look at `components\samples\com\rim\samples\device\blackberry\browser\BrowserFieldDemo.java`

Comment: I am using the BrowserFieldDemo example of blackberry JDE os 4.7,its been working fine on simulator,but when i execute on device 9550 storm,it starts buffering,but doesnt display the webpage from url.Somewhere i found a post,where they asked to append ";interface=true".I tried that but,still its not displaying the webpage on device,whereas in simulator its working fine.Please help

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the problem lies with the browser field per se. Rather with communications.

The people in the post that you refer to were probably suggesting ";deviceside=true" as this gets around the "BES effect" in a simulator.

You may wish to experiment with running the MDS emulator alongside the simulator session as well. There are a number of posts that discuss the impact of deviceside and simulation. You can test in code to see if you are running a simulator so that you can programmatically influence the "BES effect".